# Why is fetch() sending an empty body?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

In my JavaScript client I have:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append('Authorization', 'Token token=redacted>');
myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
myHeaders.append('Accept', 'application/json');
var myPost = {method: 'POST', headers: myHeaders};  
var myBody = {body: 'id=1234&result=true&url=http://example.com'}
// for example; generated dynamically but I've checked it works
fetch(database.getValue("base") + "/task/from_chrome", myPost, myBody).then (#etc
```

Why, then, am I getting the following on the server side (in Rails)?

```
> request.body.read
=> ""
```

The server side code has been previously proven; it's an issue with the JavaScript on the client side that I've had to rewrite to use fetch().

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch/fetch

window.fetch takes only 2 params, try this:

```
var myPost = {
  method: 'POST', 
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: 'id=1234&result=true&url=http://example.com'};  
fetch(database.getValue("base") + "/task/from_chrome", myPost).then
```

Comment: Very close, thanks. From there, I just had to generate the body string by passing a hash to JSON.stringify().